# why writes are not failing if replication factor is 3 but only 2 nodes are up

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have got 2 Cassandra nodes up

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\codingjedi>docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                                       NAMES
1923093e84f3        app:30may2020   "/bin/sh -c 'codingj…"   21 hours ago        Up 22 minutes                 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                      hardcore_bardeen
381fd5996008        app:30may2020   "/bin/sh -c 'codingj…"   21 hours ago        Exited (255) 24 minutes ago                                                               stupefied_wozniak
85dd140e19dd        ca795bbd8fd7              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago        Up 24 minutes                 7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp                 cassandra2
f70caa70fe81        ca795bbd8fd7              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago        Up 25 minutes                 7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp   cassandra1
```

The Replication Factor for my Keyspace is 3

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace mykeyspace;

CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

But when I run a query to add in the database, it successfully gets executed.

Question  - Shouldn't the query fail?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I am getting confused between Replication Factor (RF) and Consistency Level (CL). If less no. of nodes are up then the query will still work as long as Consistency Level is satisfied. The Consistency Level is one so the code works. If I change CL to 3 then the query fails. Regarding RF, when the 3rd node comes up then it gets the data from other 2 nodes.